# local site comes properly but when we deploy same folder on server ... it shows broken pages

Tags: wordpress

I have create a website in wordpress, it was working properly on localhost without any disturbance.But when i deployed same folder to server then it was disturbing , it shows broken pages as shown in the image [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2eKO.jpg)

please find the solution for me
thank you

Comment: what do you mean by some folder you need to upload all setup of WordPress with plugins and themes directories? into the image clearly seem that your theme CSS not working?

Comment: but css is working on localhost, then why it is not working on server

Comment: did you check it on live server that css is into themes directory or not?

Comment: can you explain the process you upload your localhost setup to the live?

Answer (score 0):

**Example**: yourlocalwebsite.com

**Example**: yourlivewebsite.com

**Step 1** Upload you all local files or WordPress setup to the live server.

**Step 2** Export your localhost database and edit it with notpad++ editor.

**Step 3** find your local website name into notpad++ something yourlocalwebsite.com  then go to replace tab and replace your yourlocalwebsite.com to yourlivewebsite.com. now save it.

**Step 4** check database name username and password into wp-config.php it should be correct which one you using live server database.

**Step 5** go to you live database and take backup it then removes it and then imports your local database now.

**Step 6** for making sure go to wp_options table and check the URL it should be now yourlivewebsite.com if not then change it

**Step 7** go to wp-admin and set the permalinks to the post name

and check it is working fine or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your site url and home url in the wp_options table. or you can define them in your wp_config as

`define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://your-website.com');`

`define('WP_HOME', 'http://your-website.com');`

or

Go to phpmyadmin and change siteurl and home entry from wp_options table with your URL(`http://your-website.com`).