# Migrating site to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, migration

A client asked me to migrate a website to wordpress. The theme is made, everything is working fine locally and now im thinking the best way to make the migration. I'm thinking on makeing the instalation on a subfolder for testing and then moving it to the root of the server. Is there anything i need to do other than copy the files from wordpress folder to the root? Anyone know a good tutorial or a better way to make the migration?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this tutorial from Sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-migrate-a-wordpress-site-to-a-new-domain-and-hosting/)  I'm always referring to it when I want to move WP websites and it works.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i've found the solution =) i'll post it as the correct answer. again, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Example: yourlocalwebsite.com

Example: yourlivewebsite.com

**Step 1** Upload you all local files or WordPress setup to the live server.

**Step 2** Export your localhost database and edit it with notpad++ editor.

**Step 3** find your local website name into notpad++ something yourlocalwebsite.com then go to replace tab and all replace tab your yourlocalwebsite.com with yourlivewebsite.com. now save it.

**Step 4** check database name username and password into wp-config.php it should be correct which one you using live server database.

**Step 5** go to you live database and take backup it then removes it and then imports your local database now.

**Step 6** for making sure go to wp_options table and check the URL it should be now yourlivewebsite.com if not then change it

**Step 7** go to wp-admin and set the permalinks to the post name

and check it is working fine or not.

[local site comes properly but when we deploy same folder on server ... it shows broken pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644830/local-site-comes-properly-but-when-we-deploy-same-folder-on-server-it-shows/44645696#44645696)

Comment: tks for your answer but, you talk about local to live and im asking how to migrate from a subfolder in the server to the root directory of the same server. anyway, i found a tutorial explaining how to do this and its really simple. again, tks =)

Answer (score 0):

In order to migrate a Wordpress website you should 
1. Copy your www folder using FTP Client (FileZilla, Fire FTP or WinSCP).
2. Export you database (important!) and then import the database in your new Web Hosting (Like OVH or other..).

Let me know if you have any others question !

Comment: tks but i found the solution. its really simple. i'll post it here as the correct answer. Anyway, tks =)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to do lot more things than you specified.
Follow below steps :-

1. Download "Wp Migrate DB" plugin from https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/ to your existing site
2. Open db migrator. When you will try migrating, it will prompt you to give folder path and website url for new site(old site is already filled by plugin so don't change them)
3. After adding folder path and URL start db migration
4. Copy files and folders from your local to live
5. Import migrated db to new database
6. Copy new credentials for db connect to wp-config file
7. Re save permalinks, as it may won't work after migration

After this you are all set to go...

Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: tks for your answer but, you talk about local to live and im asking how to migrate from a subfolder in the server to the root directory of the same server. anyway, i found a tutorial explaining how to do this and its really simple. again, tks =)

Comment: It will have same procedure.

Answer (score 0):

followed this tutorial and worked like a charm. Wordpress installation moved to the root of the server and everythig works fine. Themes and plugins. Just made the test right now.

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/329-move-folders

Thanks for the answers.